# 406 Not Acceptable response

Tags: http, forms, error

I'm getting a 406 Not Acceptable response from a GoDaddy Shared Apache server upon making the following request **through posting a form directly from the browser**:

**HEADERS:**

```
Host: url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0)   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,es-MX;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

**REQUEST BODY**

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 17095

chk1=85727&chk2=85728&chk3=85321&chk4=85322&chk5=71861&chk6=71862&chk7=61618&chk8=61620&chk9=63054&chk10=63056&chk11=85730&chk12=85731&chk13=71344&chk14=71345&chk15=85452&chk16=85453&chk17=61963&chk18=61965&chk19=61978&chk20=61980&chk21=85738&chk22=85739&chk23=63059&chk24=63061&chk25=71864&chk26=71865&chk27=71348&chk28=71349&chk29=70715&chk30=70716&chk31=85461&chk32=85462&chk33=71867&chk34=71868&chk35=17825&chk36=17826&chk37=17615&chk38=17616&chk39=71351&chk40=71352&chk41=71354&chk42=71355&chk43=2741&chk44=2742&chk45=63049&chk46=63051&chk47=63039&chk48=63041&chk49=85733&chk50=85734&chk51=75813&chk52=75814&chk53=85736&chk54=85737&chk55=17757&chk56=17758&chk57=17622&chk58=17623&chk59=11707&chk60=11708&chk61=11709&chk62=70855&chk63=70856&chk64=70723&chk65=70724&chk66=75826&chk67=75827&chk68=11711&chk69=11712&chk70=76164&chk71=71870&chk72=71871&chk73=70719&chk74=70720&chk75=70731&chk76=70732&chk77=75823&chk78=75824&chk79=71369&chk80=71370&chk81=17630&chk82=17631&chk83=17765&chk84=17766&chk85=71873&chk86=71874&chk87=85316&chk88=85317&chk89=71876&chk90=71877&chk91=71375&chk92=71376&chk93=71378&chk94=71379&chk95=85464&chk96=85465&chk97=17619&chk98=17620&chk99=85724&chk100=85725&chk101=17789&chk102=17790&chk103=71380&chk104=71381&chk105=1614&chk106=1615&chk107=85449&chk108=85450&chk109=71384&chk110=71385&chk111=64051&chk112=64053&chk113=85319&chk114=85320&chk115=17647&chk116=17648&chk117=85325&chk118=85326&chk119=63209&chk120=63210&chk121=63211&chk122=62369&chk123=62370&chk124=62371&chk125=63142&chk126=63143&chk127=63144&chk128=62384&chk129=62385&chk130=62386&chk131=62393&chk132=62394&chk133=62395&chk134=71327&chk135=70742&chk136=70743&chk137=70744&chk138=63215&chk139=63216&chk140=63217&chk141=63140&chk142=63141&chk143=63131&chk144=63132&chk145=63218&chk146=63219&chk147=63220&chk148=62405&chk149=62406&chk150=62396&chk151=62397&chk152=62398&chk153=70740&chk154=70741&chk155=70749&chk156=70750&chk157=62408&chk158=62409&chk159=62410&chk160=70746&chk161=70747&chk162=70755&chk163=70756&chk164=70967&chk165=70968&chk166=62402&chk167=62403&chk168=62404&chk169=63212&chk170=63213&chk171=63214&chk172=71336&chk173=70736&chk174=70737&chk175=70738&chk176=63221&chk177=63222&chk178=63223&chk179=62399&chk180=62400&chk181=62401&chk182=85749&chk183=85750&chk184=63203&chk185=63204&chk186=63205&chk187=85333&chk188=85334&chk189=71806&chk190=71807&chk191=71808&chk192=62414&chk193=62415&chk194=62416&chk195=63168&chk196=63169&chk197=63170&chk198=85752&chk199=85753&chk200=62444&chk201=62445&chk202=62446&chk203=85481&chk204=85482&chk205=85483&chk206=62426&chk207=62427&chk208=62428&chk209=62450&chk210=62451&chk211=62452&chk212=85757&chk213=85758&chk214=63171&chk215=63172&chk216=63173&chk217=71815&chk218=71816&chk219=71817&chk220=71249&chk221=71250&chk222=71251&chk223=85491&chk224=85492&chk225=71819&chk226=71820&chk227=71821&chk228=71822&chk229=71823&chk230=71252&chk231=71253&chk232=71254&chk233=71255&chk234=71256&chk235=71257&chk236=62462&chk237=62463&chk238=62464&chk239=63165&chk240=63166&chk241=63167&chk242=63159&chk243=63160&chk244=63161&chk245=85755&chk246=85756&chk247=75852&chk248=75853&chk249=71824&chk250=71825&chk251=71826&chk252=62453&chk253=62454&chk254=62455&chk255=62459&chk256=62460&chk257=62461&chk258=71827&chk259=71828&chk260=71829&chk261=71270&chk262=71271&chk263=71272&chk264=62456&chk265=62457&chk266=62458&chk267=71831&chk268=71832&chk269=85328&chk270=85329&chk271=71834&chk272=71835&chk273=71276&chk274=71277&chk275=71278&chk276=71279&chk277=71280&chk278=71281&chk279=85494&chk280=85495&chk281=62477&chk282=62478&chk283=62479&chk284=71282&chk285=71283&chk286=71284&chk287=85746&chk288=85747&chk289=71285&chk290=71286&chk291=63197&chk292=63198&chk293=63199&chk294=85479&chk295=85480&chk296=70757&chk297=70758&chk298=70759&chk299=63200&chk300=63201&chk301=63202&chk302=85331&chk303=85332&chk304=71291&chk305=71292&chk306=71293&chk307=85337&chk308=85338&chk309=70762&chk310=70763&chk311=71016&chk312=85761&chk313=85762&chk314=70760&chk315=70761&chk316=71015&chk317=70766&chk318=70767&chk319=71018&chk320=75849&chk321=75850&chk322=75851&chk323=70764&chk324=70765&chk325=71017&chk326=70770&chk327=70771&chk328=71020&chk329=75846&chk330=75847&chk331=75848&chk332=62548&chk333=62549&chk334=85694&chk335=85695&chk336=63350&chk337=63351&chk338=62544&chk339=62545&chk340=70842&chk341=70843&chk342=85743&chk343=85744&chk344=63332&chk345=63333&chk346=85715&chk347=63336&chk348=63337&chk349=85716&chk350=62236&chk351=62237&chk352=85691&chk353=85692&chk354=63354&chk355=63355&chk356=62228&chk357=62229&chk358=70734&chk359=70735&chk360=85741&chk361=85742&chk362=63340&chk363=63341&chk364=85713&chk365=63346&chk366=85714&chk367=63347&chk368=71387&chk369=71388&chk370=85295&chk371=85296&chk372=64016&chk373=64017&chk374=71879&chk375=71880&chk376=71882&chk377=71883&chk378=71884&chk379=71885&chk380=71888&chk381=71889&chk382=85527&chk383=85528&chk384=71891&chk385=71892&chk386=75829&chk387=75830&chk388=71893&chk389=71894&chk390=71896&chk391=71897&chk392=64023&chk393=64024&chk394=85767&chk395=85768&chk396=85292&chk397=85293&chk398=85782&chk399=85783&chk400=71389&chk401=71390&chk402=85531&chk403=85532&chk404=85473&chk405=85474&chk406=85298&chk407=85299&chk408=85769&chk409=85770&chk410=64029&chk411=64030&chk412=71393&chk413=71394&chk414=85470&chk415=85471&chk416=85764&chk417=85765&chk418=71396&chk419=71397&chk420=85785&chk421=85786&chk422=85476&chk423=85477&chk424=64014&chk425=64015&chk426=71294&chk427=71295&chk428=71296&chk429=85304&chk430=85305&chk431=64034&chk432=64035&chk433=71842&chk434=71843&chk435=71844&chk436=71837&chk437=71838&chk438=71839&chk439=71840&chk440=71846&chk441=71847&chk442=85533&chk443=85534&chk444=71848&chk445=71849&chk446=71850&chk447=71851&chk448=71852&chk449=71854&chk450=71855&chk451=64041&chk452=64042&chk453=85775&chk454=85776&chk455=85777&chk456=85301&chk457=85302&chk458=85787&chk459=85788&chk460=85789&chk461=71297&chk462=71298&chk463=71299&chk464=85537&chk465=85538&chk466=85307&chk467=85308&chk468=85778&chk469=85779&chk470=64046&chk471=64047&chk472=64048&chk473=71300&chk474=71301&chk475=71302&chk476=85772&chk477=85773&chk478=85774&chk479=71303&chk480=71304&chk481=71305&chk482=85791&chk483=85792&chk484=85499&chk485=64038&chk486=85500&chk487=85501&chk488=64039&chk489=71309&chk490=71310&chk491=71311&chk492=64032&chk493=64033&chk494=71914&chk495=71436&chk496=70846&chk497=71437&chk498=71438&chk499=8563&chk500=70840&chk501=71441&chk502=63500&chk503=71442&chk504=71443&chk505=4058&chk506=70953&chk507=71916&chk508=71917&chk509=71918&chk510=71444&chk511=71919&chk512=71445&chk513=72078&chk514=72072&chk515=75932&chk516=75933&chk517=72075&chk518=72076&chk519=85371&chk520=85514&chk521=75934&chk522=72079&chk523=85515&chk524=75927&chk525=72082&chk526=72083&chk527=75926&chk528=85398&chk529=75929&chk530=72074&chk531=85516&chk532=85370&chk533=72084&chk534=75786&chk535=75787&chk536=85151&chk537=71102&chk538=71116&chk539=85159&chk540=75788&chk541=75789&chk542=71101&chk543=71115&chk544=75782&chk545=75783&chk546=85205&chk547=71782&chk548=71783&chk549=85367&chk550=85368&chk551=75784&chk552=75785&chk553=71920&chk554=71921&chk555=85212&chk556=71922&chk557=71923&chk558=85432&chk559=85433&chk560=75780&chk561=75781&chk562=85809&chk563=85810&chk564=85814&chk565=85815&chk566=85812&chk567=85813&chk568=71786&chk569=71787&chk570=85208&chk571=71788&chk572=85362&chk573=85363&chk574=71790&chk575=71791&chk576=85806&chk577=85807&chk578=85364&chk579=85365&chk580=85358&chk581=85359&chk582=85428&chk583=85429&chk584=75800&chk585=75801&chk586=85426&chk587=85427&chk588=71792&chk589=71793&chk590=71966&chk591=71969&chk592=71967&chk593=71970&chk594=71968&chk595=71971&chk596=61851&chk597=63228&chk598=63229&chk599=61852&chk600=61854&chk601=63231&chk602=12185&chk603=12193&chk604=12186&chk605=12194&chk606=12187&chk607=12195&chk608=61855&chk609=63232&chk610=61856&chk611=63233&chk612=61858&chk613=63235&chk614=71455&chk615=71456&chk616=71458&chk617=71459&chk618=71460&chk619=71462&chk620=71463&chk621=71464&chk622=71466&chk623=85416&chk624=85278&chk625=85417&chk626=85279&chk627=25788&chk628=24746&chk629=25789&chk630=24752&chk631=25791&chk632=24747&chk633=24753&chk634=25792&chk635=63605&chk636=62164&chk637=63606&chk638=62165&chk639=71949&chk640=71934&chk641=71935&chk642=71950&chk643=25794&chk644=24750&chk645=24756&chk646=25795&chk647=25803&chk648=24749&chk649=24755&chk650=25804&chk651=71946&chk652=71931&chk653=71932&chk654=71947&chk655=24751&chk656=25797&chk657=25798&chk658=24757&chk659=85414&chk660=85280&chk661=85415&chk662=85281&chk663=25376&chk664=25800&chk665=25377&chk666=25801&chk667=71939&chk668=71960&chk669=71965&chk670=71944&chk671=70951&chk672=70952&chk673=85848&chk674=85849&chk675=63612&chk676=85717&chk677=63613&chk678=85718&chk679=62239&chk680=62240&chk681=62231&chk682=62232&chk683=85831&chk684=85832&chk685=6497&chk686=6498&chk687=6499&chk688=85345&chk689=85346&chk690=71908&chk691=75937&chk692=75938&chk693=71909&chk694=75939&chk695=71910&chk696=63374&chk697=63375&chk698=63377&chk699=85834&chk700=85835&chk701=62254&chk702=62255&chk703=62257&chk704=85842&chk705=85843&chk706=63370&chk707=63371&chk708=63373&chk709=71421&chk710=71422&chk711=71423&chk712=70825&chk713=70826&chk714=70827&chk715=85506&chk716=85507&chk717=71912&chk718=71913&chk719=6421&chk720=6422&chk721=6423&chk722=63386&chk723=63387&chk724=63389&chk725=63378&chk726=63379&chk727=63381&chk728=85837&chk729=85838&chk730=25746&chk731=25747&chk732=25749&chk733=70822&chk734=70823&chk735=70824&chk736=70831&chk737=70832&chk738=70833&chk739=11765&chk740=11766&chk741=11767&chk742=70828&chk743=70829&chk744=70830&chk745=70837&chk746=70838&chk747=70839&chk748=25738&chk749=25739&chk750=25741&chk751=85340&chk752=85341&chk753=85509&chk754=85510&chk755=6434&chk756=6435&chk757=6436&chk758=85828&chk759=85829&chk760=6494&chk761=6495&chk762=6496&chk763=70819&chk764=70820&chk765=70821&chk766=6503&chk767=6504&chk768=6505&chk769=85343&chk770=85344&chk771=85349&chk772=85350&chk773=61827&chk774=63104&chk775=63105&chk776=61828&chk777=61829&chk778=63106&chk779=71467&chk780=72038&chk781=72039&chk782=71468&chk783=71469&chk784=72040&chk785=62241&chk786=62242&chk787=62243&chk788=61836&chk789=63113&chk790=63114&chk791=61837&chk792=61838&chk793=63115&chk794=61824&chk795=63101&chk796=61825&chk797=63102&chk798=63103&chk799=61826&chk800=61830&chk801=63107&chk802=61831&chk803=63108&chk804=61832&chk805=63109&chk806=72035&chk807=71654&chk808=71655&chk809=72036&chk810=72037&chk811=71656&chk812=63098&chk813=61821&chk814=61822&chk815=63099&chk816=61823&chk817=63100&chk818=61806&chk819=63083&chk820=61807&chk821=63084&chk822=61808&chk823=63085&chk824=61809&chk825=63086&chk826=63087&chk827=61810&chk828=61811&chk829=63088&chk830=63089&chk831=61812&chk832=61813&chk833=63090&chk834=61814&chk835=63091&chk836=61818&chk837=63095&chk838=63096&chk839=61819&chk840=61820&chk841=63097&chk842=61815&chk843=63092&chk844=61816&chk845=63093&chk846=63094&chk847=61817&chk848=63110&chk849=61833&chk850=61834&chk851=63111&chk852=63112&chk853=61835&chk854=85421&chk855=85272&chk856=85273&chk857=85422&chk858=85423&chk859=85274&chk860=25778&chk861=19275&chk862=19276&chk863=25779&chk864=19277&chk865=25780&chk866=25769&chk867=19269&chk868=25770&chk869=19270&chk870=25771&chk871=19271&chk872=63607&chk873=62166&chk874=63608&chk875=62167&chk876=63609&chk877=62168&chk878=71924&chk879=71954&chk880=71925&chk881=71955&chk882=71926&chk883=71956&chk884=19281&chk885=25772&chk886=19282&chk887=25773&chk888=19283&chk889=25774&chk890=25781&chk891=19284&chk892=19285&chk893=25782&chk894=25783&chk895=19286&chk896=71951&chk897=71927&chk898=71952&chk899=71928&chk900=71953&chk901=71929&chk902=19278&chk903=25775&chk904=25776&chk905=19279&chk906=19280&chk907=25777&chk908=85418&chk909=85275&chk910=85419&chk911=85276&chk912=85420&chk913=85277&chk914=25784&chk915=25372&chk916=25785&chk917=25373&chk918=25786&chk919=25374&chk920=72049&chk921=72050&chk922=72051&chk923=72052&chk924=72053&chk925=72054&chk926=72058&chk927=72059&chk928=72060&chk929=72055&chk930=72056&chk931=72057&chk932=72046&chk933=72047&chk934=72048&chk935=72043&chk936=72044&chk937=72045&chk938=85818&chk939=63241&chk940=71208&chk941=85352&chk942=70957&chk943=70956&chk944=85356&chk945=71794&chk946=63403&chk947=85819&chk948=70853&chk949=71210&chk950=85518&chk951=62592&chk952=63449&chk953=62596&chk954=85822&chk955=63256&chk956=63402&chk957=72042&chk958=71211&chk959=85519&chk960=71795&chk961=62607&chk962=70848&chk963=85521&chk964=71796&chk965=71797&chk966=63245&chk967=62619&chk968=71212&chk969=71213&chk970=85520&chk971=70961&chk972=70960&chk973=62604&chk974=63442&chk975=63440&chk976=85820&chk977=85823&chk978=75870&chk979=85825&chk980=62622&chk981=63254&chk982=85351&chk983=85821&chk984=63243&chk985=62602&chk986=62598&chk987=70850&chk988=75876&chk989=71217&chk990=62603&chk991=71798&chk992=70849&chk993=70852&chk994=75874&chk995=71219&chk996=63253&chk997=62601&chk998=63244&chk999=85353&chk1000=71800&chk1001=85354&chk1002=85826&chk1003=71801&chk1004=63446&chk1005=71221&chk1006=71222&chk1007=85522&chk1008=63445&chk1009=85719&chk1010=62613&chk1011=70965&chk1012=70964&chk1013=71223&chk1014=62600&chk1015=62617&chk1016=85817&chk1017=71224&chk1018=85824&chk1019=62621&chk1020=63443&chk1021=85517&chk1022=71226&chk1023=70847&chk1024=63258&chk1025=85355&chk1026=62599&chk1027=85357&chk1028=70955&chk1029=70954&chk1030=61847&chk1031=63076&chk1032=63079&chk1033=61850&chk1034=61846&chk1035=63075&chk1036=61848&chk1037=63077&chk1038=71454&chk1039=72071&chk1040=61845&chk1041=63074&chk1042=61840&chk1043=63069&chk1044=61841&chk1045=63070&chk1046=61842&chk1047=63071&chk1048=61844&chk1049=63073&chk1050=61843&chk1051=63072&chk1052=61849&chk1053=63078&chk1054=72065&chk1055=83858&chk1056=72064&chk1057=72067&chk1058=72069&chk1059=72070&chk1060=72066&chk1061=85687&chk1062=72062&chk1063=72112&chk1064=72068&chk1065=72061&chk1066=85688&chk1067=71972&chk1068=71973&chk1069=61859&chk1070=63122&chk1071=20562&chk1072=25768&chk1073=63123&chk1074=61860&chk1075=71453&chk1076=72085&chk1077=75923&chk1078=75924&chk1079=72088&chk1080=75922&chk1081=63489&chk1082=72089&chk1083=85373&chk1084=85699&chk1085=75925&chk1086=72091&chk1087=71414&chk1088=72093&chk1089=71416&chk1090=85399&chk1091=75920&chk1092=85372&chk1093=72011&chk1094=72006&chk1095=85850&chk1096=85851&chk1097=72012&chk1098=72001&chk1099=71995&chk1100=72000&chk1101=71996&chk1102=85424&chk1103=72003&chk1104=71999&chk1105=72002&chk1106=71997&chk1107=71994&chk1108=71998&chk1109=72015&chk1110=75919&chk1111=72031&chk1112=75904&chk1113=75903&chk1114=72029&chk1115=72026&chk1116=75908&chk1117=75911&chk1118=72032&chk1119=72033&chk1120=75905&chk1121=85442&chk1122=3040&chk1123=3039&chk1124=87019&chk1125=3247&chk1126=87126&chk1127=3170&chk1128=3171&chk1129=3172&chk1130=3227&chk1131=75940&chk1132=85708&chk1133=71739&chk1134=85704&chk1135=75967&chk1136=85700&chk1137=63940&chk1138=75779&chk1139=85214&chk1140=71748&chk1141=85701&chk1142=95120&chk1143=71067&chk1144=71090&chk1145=71068&chk1146=71063&chk1147=71064&chk1148=95119&chk1149=71077&chk1150=85722&chk1151=87331&chk1152=71091&chk1153=71085&chk1154=71086&chk1155=71741&chk1156=18385&chk1157=85712&chk1158=75969&chk1159=85709&chk1160=63937&chk1161=63939&chk1162=63938&chk1163=85441&chk1164=71071&chk1165=75941&chk1166=85703&chk1167=75942&chk1168=63924&chk1169=85705&chk1170=85706&chk1171=71069&chk1172=63955&chk1173=85702&chk1174=85720&chk1175=3161&chk1176=71087&chk1177=71088&chk1178=75968&chk1179=71089&chk1180=85213&chk1181=71078&chk1182=71072&chk1183=71073&chk1184=71074&chk1185=71081&chk1186=71083&chk1187=71082&chk1188=85711&chk1189=85721&chk1190=75883&chk1191=85009&chk1192=85013&chk1193=75884&chk1194=85390&chk1195=85391&chk1196=85007&chk1197=75898&chk1198=75899&chk1199=85011&chk1200=85437&chk1201=85438&chk1202=75886&chk1203=75953&chk1204=75954&chk1205=75887&chk1206=85797&chk1207=85798&chk1208=85800&chk1209=85801&chk1210=85374&chk1211=85375&chk1212=85393&chk1213=85394&chk1214=85377&chk1215=85378&chk1216=85384&chk1217=85385&chk1218=85380&chk1219=85381&chk1220=85382&chk1221=85387&chk1222=85388&chk1223=85008&chk1224=75889&chk1225=75890&chk1226=85012&chk1227=75880&chk1228=75944&chk1229=75881&chk1230=75945&chk1231=85802&chk1232=85803&chk1233=85396&chk1234=85397&chk1235=75962&chk1236=75895&chk1237=75963&chk1238=75896&chk1239=85794&chk1240=85795&chk1241=75964&chk1242=75891&chk1243=75892&chk1244=75965&chk1245=85435&chk1246=85436&chk1247=75947&chk1248=75901&chk1249=85010&chk1250=75902&chk1251=85228&chk1252=85408&chk1253=85409&chk1254=85235&chk1255=85400&chk1256=85222&chk1257=85401&chk1258=85229&chk1259=85412&chk1260=85224&chk1261=85231&chk1262=85413&chk1263=85402&chk1264=85223&chk1265=85230&chk1266=85403&chk1267=85226&chk1268=85406&chk1269=85407&chk1270=85233&chk1271=85410&chk1272=85225&chk1273=85232&chk1274=85411&chk1275=85227&chk1276=85404&chk1277=85405&chk1278=85234&chk1279=85311&chk1280=85312&chk1281=85550&chk1282=85541&chk1283=85309&chk1284=85310&chk1285=85539&chk1286=85540&chk1287=85313&chk1288=85314&chk1289=85598&chk1290=85597&chk1291=85596&chk1292=85599&chk1293=85686&chk1294=85684&chk1295=85678&chk1296=85681&chk1297=85685&chk1298=85680&chk1299=85682&chk1300=85679&chk1301=85683&actualizar_costo=
```

I don't understand what the problem is because it works fine with smaller requests. Besides max_input_vars is set to 3,000 and I'm only posting about 1,302 fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem: GoDaddy.

Comment: Even if `max_input_vars` was exceeded, it should not result in a 406 (you get a trappable PHP warning). This sounds like it could be a mod_security (or GoDaddy server) issue? Is mod_security enabled on your account? Do you have access to customize or disable this in your control panel?

Comment: @w3d I´m waiting for godaddys response. It might be a mod_security issue, and I cannot disable it with current permissions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your request body is very large. If I'm correct, your request body is at least 10.4 KB in size because of all those fields that begin with chk and that have a value of at least 5 characters. That makes 10 characters (including equals and a one-digit chk number). Multiply 10 by 1024 fields crafted this way and you get 10.2 KB request size minimum.

Ask Godaddy to check their apache configuration file for all configuration lines that begin with "limit" because there are settings that can be applied to httpd.conf that can limit the size of request data people can apply to the server.

This URL can provide details:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

If you request anything thats above the limit that the server deems acceptable, then you can expect an error.

Comment: "your request body is at least 10.4 KB" - or _exactly_ 17095 B (16.7 KB) as stated in the `Content-Length` header. ;) +1

Comment: Wow, I overlooked that content-length header. Good one.